Cannot build for Apple Watch with on-demand resources
I am creating an app for iOS which contains an Apple Watch app embedded.
I have turned ON Build Settings > Enable On Demand Resources and marked some assets inside a .xcassets file as on-demand.
This is the error I see.
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
: error: Cannot enable on demand resources for the platform "watchOS". Consider disabling the ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES build setting.
/* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
/Users/myMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cuaaa-bfkiwkbyypwohfahhwdaqhzirchn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/cuaaa.build/Debug-watchos/cuaaa Watch App.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
/Users/myMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cuaaa-bfkiwkbyypwohfahhwdaqhzirchn/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/OnDemandResources/.watchkitapp.cucarobga-747198866748abb7711ab70510b9c29e.assetpack/Assets.car
/Users/myMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/cuaaa-bfkiwkbyypwohfahhwdaqhzirchn/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/cuaaa Watch App.app/Assets.car

Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code

The problem happens while compiling asset catalogs.
The issue is that in theory, On-Demand Resources is something compatible with watchOS.
The error you see is from some dummy project I have created of a watch-only app I have created to see if the issue was of my project. It is not.
Any ideas?

You say "in theory, On-Demand Resources is something compatible with watchOS" and yet the error message tells you explicitly that you cannot use on demand resources with watchOS, so your theory is wrong.
From Xcode help:

On-demand resources are available for iOS and tvOS apps

You need to ensure that any asset catalog that is part of your watchOS target does not include any on demand resources.

Ok, so explain me why NSBundleResourceRequest an API used to download on-demand resources are available for watchOS 2.0+ ? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundleresourcerequest

The availability of that API on WatchOS doesn't mean that on demand resources can be used on watchOS. It could be a documentation error or Apple includes that class in Foundation for WatchOS because they didn't think to take it out or maybe they planned or plan to support on demand resources at some point. That class is just one part of on demand resource support. The error message from the compiler and other documentation states that on demand resources are not available for watchOS.
